# Properies file values doesn't appear in my variable

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

Learning automation testing at the moment and I can't understand what is the problem with my code. I'm trying to get information from .properties file and use it as variables. I'm receiving an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\resources\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

However, I'm sure that my path is right. Tried in different variations like `//resources//config...` and even with `\\`,  still the same problem.

This is my code where I try to get information from config.properties file:

```
@Test
public void myFirstTest() {
        LoginPage log = new LoginPage();

        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("../resources/config.properties")) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(reader);
            String username = (String) properties.get("username");
            String password = (String) properties.get("password");
            System.out.println("h" + username);
            log.insertUsername(username);
            log.insertPassword(password);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And this is how looks my `config.properties`

```
username = myUserName1
password = myTestPass1
```

And this is the architecture of my files:

[image]

P.S. I'm trying to reach source file from tests -> `LabelsAndFoldersTest.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you provided of `config.properties` is not correct

As i can see the image of your project structure you have a `src/resources` folder under your project and there you have places `config.properties`

Change the file path to `src/resources/config.properties`

```
try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("src/resources/config.properties"))
```

Comment: Wow, it was so simple.. Thank you !

Comment: @HenryB Glad to hear  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you specify relative file path. And it depends on System.property("user.dir")

To figure out what the value of it just print it.

```java
String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("The current working directory is " + currentDirectory);
```

If your file is located in resources directory, then I guess it will be packed into jar file. So the better way is to load resource with this code

```java
// if config.properties located in root of resources
InputStream io = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(io)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's much easier to load files using the ClassLoader. Use getClass().getResourceAsStream() to get files that are on your classpath:

```
InputStream is = youClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/full/path/config.properties");
if(is != null) {
    Properties adminProps = new Properties();
    adminProps.load(is);
```

Note that the leading slash is very important.

Comment: Momo, you option gives me a null. When I create Properties object, I try to use for getProperty(); And after sysout it's null. Any ideas?